# A way to have a rolling summation

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, window-functions

I have the below dataset. In the below example records for the year 1993. The `Tgrowth` column is `start - end`. `Started` is the number of employees that joined on a specific month and `ended` is the number of employees that left for the same month.

[image]

```
SELECT 
        r.Tgrowth,
            CASE
                WHEN t.mon_num = 1 THEN 'JAN'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 2 THEN 'FEB'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 3 THEN 'MAR'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 4 THEN 'APR'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 5 THEN 'MAY'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 6 THEN 'JUN'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 7 THEN 'JUL'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 8 THEN 'AUG'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 9 THEN 'SEP'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 10 THEN 'OCT'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 11 THEN 'NOV'
                WHEN t.mon_num = 12 THEN 'DEC'
            END AS myMONTH
    FROM
        (SELECT 1 mon_num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) t
    LEFT JOIN Reports r ON t.mon_num = r.theMONTH
        AND r.Tyear = 1993
    GROUP BY r.Tgrowth , myMONTH
    ORDER BY t.mon_num ASC
```

The result set for the above is as follows,

```
Tgrowth Month
1      JAN
0      FEB
2      MAR
0      APR
0      MAY
0      JUN
0      JUL
0      AUG
0      SEP
0      OCT
0      NOV
0      DEC
```

Instead I would like the result to show a rolling sum i.e. add to the `Tgrowth` field. Something like the below,

```
growth  Emp_Count   myMONTH
1          1        JAN
0          1        FEB
2          3        MAR
0          3        APR
0          3        MAY
0          3        JUN
0          3        JUL
0          3        AUG
0          3        SEP
0          3        OCT
0          3        NOV
0          3        DEC
```

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: @Fahmi vesion is 8.0.17

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - that said, this kind of problem is probably best handled in application code

Comment: Thanks for your input, that said my question fulfills the requirement set in that link you put up.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `theDate`?

Comment: @GMB the datatype for thedate is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. use join
2. use variables

The method of using join is as following:

```
SELECT
       t1.Tgrowth,
       sum(t2.Tgrowth) as Emp_Count,
       CASE
        WHEN t1.Month = 1 THEN 'JAN'
        WHEN t1.Month = 2 THEN 'FEB'
        WHEN t1.Month = 3 THEN 'MAR'
        WHEN t1.Month = 4 THEN 'APR'
        WHEN t1.Month = 5 THEN 'MAY'
        WHEN t1.Month = 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN t1.Month = 7 THEN 'JUL'
        WHEN t1.Month = 8 THEN 'AUG'
        WHEN t1.Month = 9 THEN 'SEP'
        WHEN t1.Month = 10 THEN 'OCT'
        WHEN t1.Month = 11 THEN 'NOV'
        WHEN t1.Month = 12 THEN 'DEC'
       END AS myMONTH
FROM (
    SELECT
    case
        when r.growth is not null then r.growth
        when r.growth is null then 0
    END as Tgrowth,
    t.mon_num AS Month
FROM
    (SELECT 1 mon_num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) t
LEFT JOIN Reports r ON t.mon_num = r.themonth
    AND r.theYear = 1993
GROUP BY r.growth , Month
ORDER BY t.mon_num ASC
         ) as t1 join (
    SELECT
    case
        when r.growth is not null then r.growth
        when r.growth is null then 0
    END as Tgrowth,
    t.mon_num AS Month
FROM
    (SELECT 1 mon_num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) t
LEFT JOIN Reports r ON t.mon_num = r.themonth
    AND r.theYear = 1993
GROUP BY r.growth , Month
ORDER BY t.mon_num ASC
         ) as t2 on t1.Month >= t2.Month group by t1.Month;
```

Use variables solution is as following:

```
SET @num := 0;
select
       Tgrowth,
       @num := @num + Tgrowth as Emp_Count,
       CASE
        WHEN t1.Month = 1 THEN 'JAN'
        WHEN t1.Month = 2 THEN 'FEB'
        WHEN t1.Month = 3 THEN 'MAR'
        WHEN t1.Month = 4 THEN 'APR'
        WHEN t1.Month = 5 THEN 'MAY'
        WHEN t1.Month = 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN t1.Month = 7 THEN 'JUL'
        WHEN t1.Month = 8 THEN 'AUG'
        WHEN t1.Month = 9 THEN 'SEP'
        WHEN t1.Month = 10 THEN 'OCT'
        WHEN t1.Month = 11 THEN 'NOV'
        WHEN t1.Month = 12 THEN 'DEC'
       END AS myMONTH
from (
SELECT
    case
        when r.growth is not null then r.growth
        when r.growth is null then 0
    END as Tgrowth,
    t.mon_num AS Month
FROM
    (SELECT 1 mon_num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) t
LEFT JOIN Reports r ON t.mon_num = r.themonth
    AND r.theYear = 1993
GROUP BY r.growth , Month
ORDER BY t.mon_num ASC ) t1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend a recursive query to generate the dates, and then window functions and aggregation.

If you want the whole 1993 year:

```
with dates as (
    select '1993-01-01' dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 month from dates where dt < '1993-12-01'
)
select
    date_format(d.dt, '%b') mymonth,
    coalesce(sum(started), 0) - coalesce(sum(ended), 0) growth,
    sum(coalesce(sum(started), 0) - coalesce(sum(ended), 0)) over(order by d.dt) emp_count
from dates d
left join reports r on r.theDate >= d.dt and r.theDate < d.dt + interval 1 month
group by d.dt
order by d.dt
```

This assumes that `theDate` is stored as a `date` datatype and not a string (else, you would need to convert it first, using `str_to_date()`).

This also takes in account the possibility that the table may contain several rows for a given month. If that's not the case, then there is no need for aggregation:

```
with dates as (
    select '1993-01-01' dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 month from dates where dt < '1993-12-01'
)
select
    date_format(d.dt, '%b') mymonth,
    coalesce(started, 0) - coalesce(ended, 0) growth,
    sum(coalesce(started, 0) - coalesce(ended, 0)) over(order by d.dt) emp_count
from dates d
left join reports r on r.theDate >= d.dt and r.theDate < d.dt + interval 1 month
order by d.dt
```